# spec is surjective for ring hom which is a free module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

If $A \rightarrow B$ is a ring hom of noetherian rings that makes $B$ into a free $A$ module (not enecessarily finitely generated), i've been led to believe that $spec(B) \rightarrow spec (A)$ is surjective.  Is this true? and how to prove that? thank you.

Comment: @KReiser thank you!